# Conversion failed! FFMpeg with custom exe in a pipe

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I need to use a batch file with FFmpeg pipe query. I have a set of images (`img0.bmp, img1.bmp, img2.bmp`) and I need FFmpeg to iterate through them and pass raw data to my custom .exe.

So, the query looks like this

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i img%01d.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | MY_CUSTOM_EXE
```

and code of the custom exe is really simple like this

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The trick of this story is that if I pass to FFmpeg exe just one image like this `... -i img0.bmp ...` it works, but if there is a set `... -i img%01d.bmp ...`, so I get such an error after the very first interaction:

```
Input #0, image2, from 'img%01d.bmp':
  Duration: 00:00:00.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, pal8, 4096x3000, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y800 / 0x30303859), gray, 4096x3000, q=2-31, 2457600 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 rawvideo
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=   12000kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=2457600.0kbits/s speed=0.999x
video:12000kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
Conversion failed!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In addition if I use this query like this

ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i img%01d.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe:

or with other ffmpeg pipe commands

ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i %input% -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -framerate 30 ...

it also works perfectly.

So the problem in the MY_CUSTOM_EXE, but what could it be if it has only one line of code?

Comment: What happens if you do a `while(std::cin >> mychar){}` instead of just exiting.  Maybe ffmpeg is disappointed nobody was answering the doorbell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must let your program consume the output from ffmpeg otherwise you get the errors you describe.

I tested my hunch and came back with:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Broken pipe
```

So a simple

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    char c;
    while(std::cin >> c){}  // consume everything the pipe offers
}  // return 0 implied.
```

Will fix this particular error.

Comment: but you know, looks like smth weird here as it means that `ffmpeg` pass through the pipe all the bytes, I mean for example if I have a set of 10k images, so it means that I get as in input all the bytes in one step... I think it should be a way to get images one by one...